# Problem with bridge-server ERRO[0062] seen every 60 sec

Tags: bridge-server

This server was working fine with this config for like over 12 months with this same config.  Now for reasons unknown I get:
WARN[0001] accounts.authorizing_seed not provided. /authorize endpoint will not be available. 
INFO[0001] Started listening for new payments            accountId=GDUPQLNDVSUKJ4XKQQDITC7RFYCJTROCR6AMUBAMPGBIZXQU4UTAGX7C cursor=now service=PaymentListener
ERRO[0062] Error while streaming: only expected 1 event, got: 0  service=PaymentListener
INFO[0062] Sleeping...                                   service=PaymentListener
INFO[0072] Streaming connection closed. Restarting...    service=PaymentListener
INFO[0072] Started listening for new payments            accountId=GDUPQLNDVSUKJ4XKQQDITC7RFYCJTROCR6AMUBAMPGBIZXQU4UTAGX7C cursor=now service=PaymentListener
**ERRO[0133] Error while streaming: only expected 1 event, got: 0  service=PaymentListener**

bolded ERRO[XXXX] above repeats about every 60 sec.

I tried clear of the mysql database didn't help.  This is now running on testnet.  I have the same code running on livenet without any problems.

config file contents (with passwords removed):

## Bridge server bridge.cfg example

port = 8003
horizon = "https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org"
network_passphrase = "Test SDF Network ; September 2015"
api_key = ""
mac_key = ""

[[assets]]
code="USD"
issuer="GCEZWKCA5VLDNRLN3RPRJMRZOX3Z6G5CHCGSNFHEYVXM3XOJMDS674JZ"

[database]
type = "mysql"
url = "username:password@/gateway_test_store?parseTime=true"

[accounts]

receiving_account_id = "GDUPQLNDVSUKJ4XKQQDITC7RFYCJTROCR6AMUBAMPGBIZXQU4UTAGX7C"

[callbacks]

receive = "https://www.funtracker.site/test_store/?route=extension/payment/stellar_net/callback&token=notset"

error = "http://localhost:8004/error"

Comment: although we do see these errors it would appear as if the bridge-server is still working without flaw.  I tested sending funds to the listen account and I note the added mysql database entry and note in my apache logs that the post event did go off.  So I guess we might ignore these errors for now?